# Automatic photo classification for desktop

Tags: linux, file-management, photography, machine-learning

Google Images can automatically filter images by their content.

For example, you can find all images with food. It also can create thematic albums by itself.

But Google Photos has very slow interface, because it is web-application. Also its conception of albums is not suitable to me. I need folders.

Is there any desktop application, which can classify photos using ML algorithms?

Comment: Appears to still be a research topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_image_annotation

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Most of things, that we use every are still actively researched.

Answer (score 3):

Not a desktop Application as such but the [Keras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keras) python [Deep Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning) library with [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) is now available pre-trained for image recognition there is a very good walk-through with all of the necessary code and a grounding on the theory at [pyimagesearch](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/03/20/imagenet-vggnet-resnet-inception-xception-keras/).  Note that on the first run there are some big downloads to perform.

Comment: Thank you! I think, I will just write a Python script, to batch-procces the files. I will not mark your question as answer, because it not fully answers my question.