# AI-based classification for local image

Tags: photography, image-recognition, classification

AI photo classification is everywhere. When you upload pictures to Amazon Photos, they are automatically classified with groups like "Plant", "Car", "Tree", etc. When you upload to Facebook, the same thing happens and the image will get an *alt* tag something like *"Image may contain: 2 people, people sitting and indoor"*.

I want this power for myself.

Specifically, I want to apply it to my existing library of sorted family photos, and I want to do it automatically when I copy photos from my camera's SD card to the local drive. ("Automatically" doesn't need to be a feature; I can script that up.) I want the tags applied as XMP Subject metadata in the photo directly (or in a sidecar).

I am aware of [Amazon Rekognition](https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/), an API service I could use to write an app like this. Is there anything pre-existing?

Must run on Linux (Fedora). Open Source / free software ideal. Does not need to be a desktop app ([Automatic photo classification for desktop](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/45815/automatic-photo-classification-for-desktop).) Ideally uses a local system, but I am okay with something that calls a cloud-based API. I don't have an Nvidia card, so anything that requires CUDA is off the table for me, but I'd like to hear about it anyway, as it might help someone else (or if it's the only option, may be worth a small investment).